# How do I use a comma delimited string as query criteria on a numeric field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, criteria, type-mismatch

I've built a function that creates a comma delimited string from multiple selections in my list box. When I try to use this as the  Where clause in my sql (in VBA) I get a 'type mismatch' error - because the field I'm using with the criteria is numeric. How do I resolve this?
example:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblItemsLibrary ( Constr, Description) ...
      "WHERE (((tblItemsLibrary1.ItemsLibID) In (" & strSelectedRecords & ")));"
```

In the above example strSelectedRecords is coming in as "17,11,28" where the field is a long.

Comment: Does `strSelectedRecords` have quotes embedded in it?  If Yes why add them, if No then if `ItemsLibID` is numeric that should work...   `"WHERE tblItemsLibrary1.ItemsLibID In (17,11,28);"` would seem OK (without those extra parens).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `LIKE`:

```
INSERT INTO tblItemsLibrary ( Constr, Description)
    ...
    WHERE "," & tblItemsLibrary1.ItemsLibID) & "," LIKE "*," & strSelectedRecords & ",*"
```

Actually you might want to adjust `strSelectedRecords` to start and end with `*,` and `,*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above, the function string_split can be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblItemsLibrary
WHERE tblItemsLibrary1.ItemsLibID IN (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@numlist, ','))

Replace @numlist with your string 17,11,28
```

Another method is to construct dynamic sql and pass that on top of base sql statement:

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM tblItemsLibrary1 WHERE ItemsLibID IN 
('+@numlist+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL expression will result in:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblItemsLibrary ( Constr, Description) 
... 
WHERE (((tblItemsLibrary1.ItemsLibID) In (17,11,28)));
```

which is correct if `ItemsLibID` is numeric.

Thus, your error is probably caused by the *values* you try to insert.